# Show a div only when user hover an element for couple seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an hidden div, and I want to show the hidden div only when user's mouse over another a trigger element for several seconds instead show the hidden div once the user hover the trigger element

here is my javascript code

```
$('.c_like_icon').mouseover(


function() {
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            var comment_id=$(this).attr('data-commentId');

    $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_c_like_user.php',
    method:'post',
    data:{comment_id:comment_id},
    success:function(data){

    var like_num=$('#'+comment_id+'c_like_number').text();
    if(like_num>=1){
        $('#'+comment_id+'like_user_w').html(data);
        $('#'+comment_id+'like_user_w').show();
    }
    else{
            $('#'+comment_id+'like_user_w').hide();


    }   
    }
       })     
        }, 2000); //2 seconds
    },
    function(){
        var comment_id=$(this).attr('data-commentId');
        clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel the timeout if they hover off
            $('#'+comment_id+'like_user_w').hide();
        // do stuff when hover off
    }
    )
```

Comment: you need to share the html and other scripts that you have tried

Comment: Write a `mouseenter` handler that uses `setTimeout` to show the div after a delay.

Answer (score 5):

define a timeout in your hover in function and clear in the hover out function, to prevent it being fired if they leave before the time runs out, like this:

```
var timeout;
$('#trigger').hover(
    function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            // do stuff on hover
            $('#hiddenDiv').show();
        }, 2000); //2 seconds
    },
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel the timeout if they hover off
        // do stuff when hover off
        $('#hiddenDiv').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work because the `timeout` variable is a local variable in the first function and not available in the second function.  It must be stored somewhere that is accessible from both functions.

Comment: Instead of `var timeout = setTimeout(..)` replace it to `timeout = setTimeout(..)`, this way `timeout` is a global variable. There is no need to declare it on top, remember that javascript is based on contexts. However, your solution is also valid.

Comment: I'd like to assume the code is wrapped inside a document ready function and it would be better to keep it as local as possible

Comment: @OscarJara - implicit global variables are horrible things for code understandability and maintainability.  A variable that is intended to be global should ALWAYS be explicitly declared as global as Billy has now done.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sure, but it depends! I agree with the last solution

Comment: Does this mean I execute the first function only when the user hover on the element for 2 seconds and otherwise the execution won't be executed, Do I need to add another code to function 2 except for the clearTimeout(timeout)

Comment: @OscarJara - in my book, it NEVER depends.  One should ALWAYS explicitly declare variables you intend to be global.  Otherwise the code is tricky to understand and easy to goof up with.  In this case, the best answer would be to contain this in an IIFE so there are no global variables at all.

Comment: @KesongTse Well you should add the code to hide the div because that function will happen when the user moves the mouse out of the div.

Comment: @jfriend00 And why is it no possible to use it that way in a short piece of code and without any relation with other classes? is it a bad practice? I think there are some special cases and does not affect. Also, I agree that the correct way is the other solution

Comment: By the way, the performance is just 0.13% faster when using `var` in a simple function :-)

Comment: timeout CAN NOT be global if you are going to use this solution for more than a div !!    What happens if I hover the first element, and then hover the second one before the first timedout function executes ?

Comment: @vals in my example, I use an id, so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @KesongTse you are using `.mouseover`, you need to use[`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 5):

You can very easily do this **CSS only**. No jquery is required which presents a huge benefit as it is a big library to download.
Just use delayed transitions. Here is my example (**live demo here**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbGhi):

**HTML**

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

In this example, the ids are not necessary but I find it better to understand what happens.

**CSS**

for the purpose of this example, I'll stylize the divs (to make the hover effect more obvious) but none of the following really matters:

```
div{
    height: 50vmin;
    width: 50vmin;
    border: solid 5px black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10vmin;
}
```

and this is where the magic happens:

```
div#first:hover ~ div#second{
    transition: all 0.2s ease 1s;
    background-color: green;
}
```

We are using the css selector "~" that means "any sibling element after (and their children)". In that example it means "a div called #second that is sibling and after a div called #first that is hovered". Basically, as long as the second div is a sibling and after or contained within a sibling (that is after) of the first one, you'll get the desired effect.

And there you go. You can add more delay (change "1s" to whatever duration) before the change occurs, and you can smoothen the transition itself (change "0.2s" to whatever duration).

PS: in the CSS, don't forget to add all vendor prefixes for transition and transform. Always check caniuse.com to know which prefixes are needed. Example:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
```

Comment: This is a great idea but unfortunately, I have to use ajax to load some data form database not just simply change background color, But thanks

Comment: Yeah I was already finishing up my answer when you posted your code. So I decided to post it anyway, it can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

i know its an old question, but i think it should have a vanilla solution

```
// Element will be the triggerer
let timeOut;

element.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    // Do your stuff here
  }, 400);
});


element.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
});
```